# Python/Numpy doesn't read data properly on conversion to float

Tags: python, string, numpy, matplotlib

i've been searching the net for nearly three hours now in need of an answer to a problem i have with numpy.

I'm reading data from a .csv file into numpy arrays to plot the data in a 3d surface plot unsing matplotlib. The data acqusition is done with python's csv module. The header is read into one array, the first column into another and the rest of the data belongig to these two axes values is read into a third array.

First I oversaw that I had to convert the 'Y' array to float to be able to display it properly without mixing 'string' and 'float' arrays, that was fixed. Now my program converts the strings in the Y array properly until it finds a value like '2.633e-12' now it says

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2.673e-

when I print the corresponding value from the array before conversion it is printed like i showed above.

See the complete program code below...

I would appreciate any help you could offer, so thanks in advance...

Tim

EDIT:

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Velocities.py", line 49, in <module>
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, avel, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
  File "/usr/bin/epd_free/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1453, in plot_surface
    self.auto_scale_xyz(X, Y, Z, had_data)
  File "/usr/bin/epd_free/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 392, in auto_scale_xyz
    self.xy_dataLim.update_from_data_xy(np.array([x, y]).T, not had_data)
  File "/usr/bin/epd_free/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 854, in update_from_data_xy
    path = Path(xy)
  File "/usr/bin/epd_free/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 112, in __init__
    vertices = np.asarray(vertices, np.float_)
  File "/usr/bin/epd_free/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 235, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2.673e-
```

The lines before and after the line producing the error from my input file:

```
2.57e-12;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488;-243.476064488
2.673e-12;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317;-243.747334317
2.772e-12;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958;-244.067736958
```

I would still appreciate any answer, helping me to figure this problem out...

EDIT2:

here is the complete code as i figured out, that the conversion to float is no problem, but rather the surface plot itself causes the traceback...

```
#!/usr/bin/epd_free/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

##all the necessary imports
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import math as m
import csv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
#from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

##reading the data
#reading the velocity profiles from the "velProfiles"
eingabe = "velProfiles_kum.csv"

dat = csv.reader(open(str(eingabe), 'rb'), delimiter=';')

X=dat.next()
X.pop(0)
X=np.array(X)

Y=[]
avel=[]
for i,row in enumerate(dat):
    if i%100 == 0:
        Y.append(row.pop(0))
        avel.append([float(item) for item in row])#if item is not ''
del dat
#Y=np.array(Y)
Y=np.array(Y).astype(np.float64)
avel=np.array(avel) # converting the list into an array to be able to process it with the 3D plotting engine.

##creating the graph and the mesh needed to plot the data. (get the dimensions right!!!)
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d', lod=True)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

print("X: " + str(X.shape) + "| Y: " + str(Y.shape) + "| Z: " + str(avel.shape)) # to stdout to check the arrays' dimensions

#plotting the surface
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, avel, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)

#setting the title and the labels
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("t")
plt.title("The simulation's velocity profiles plotted over time and space")

#layout refinements
#plt.tight_layout()
#fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=.8, aspect=12) #create the colorbar after the tight_layout() command to prevent it from being drawn inside the figure.

#show it!
plt.show()
```

Comment: It sounds to me you might be confusing 2 values: the one you print, and the one which actually causes the problem.  Did you try searching your file for `2.673e-`?

Comment: Can't you use ``numpy.loadtxt`` or ``numpy.genfromtxt`` instead of the ``csv`` module? See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Can you show the first few lines of your CSV, and also include a line that contains a troublesome value?

Comment: Can you post the actual traceback so we can know which line is generating the error?

Comment: hey, i've been searching the value in question in my .csv. it looks perfectly normal. all values before said value are being read perfectly fine, if they look like '1.18e-12' or something like that. changing the values to having only two digits after the period resolves the problem but this can't be the solution...

i also tried converting values in said form manually in my python distro, so i don't see anything wrong with that...

i also don't think that there are unprintable characters in the value because i have the values as simulation output from a program i wrote in python myself...

Comment: No problem here (Python 2.7.3, NumPy 1.6.2).

Comment: using epd_free with python 2.7.3 and numpy 1.6.1 i still have the problem...

Comment: Your updated version doesn't work, since `X` is a str ('S14' numpy) type, not a float. So I'm guessing that now, mpl tries the conversion behind the scenes and fails, but it's still the same problem with your input file. Try opening the input file in another editor and see if you can see anything there.

Comment: Thanks!!! that helped. i was kind of blind, i think... now it works perfectly fine. Thank you again!